# "Take long for me" versus "take me long"

Tags: word-order

Which form is preferred in the following sentence?

> It didn't take **long for me/me long** to realize that traditional exercises failed to adequately meet the needs of persons with disabilities.

Comment: Preferred by whom?

Comment: I had to look at your question for a little while to realize that something was off. It should read: *It didn't take* ***long for me*** */* ***me long*** *to realize . . .* Both of the phrases need to end with **to**, not just the second one.

Comment: They mean different things to me. In this case, the different is very slight and can be easily ignored, but there are other cases where the difference is more noticeable. “It didn’t take long for the explosives to ignite” means the ignition happened after a short period of time; “it didn’t take the explosives long to ignite” means that the ignition lasted only a short period of time (which is obviously true, since ignitions are momentary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions are grammatical.

It's not possible to answer which is *preferred*, but the more *common* version, at least when it comes to books in print, seems to be *take me long to*.

Per [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20long%20for%20me%20to%2Ctake%20me%20long%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20long%20for%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20me%20long%20to%3B%2Cc0):

[image: take me long to]

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you. Sharing that graph was quite helpful and insightful.